# Find unique solution to certain $N$ and related $N+1$ order polynomial (one solution, numerically known, looking for proof)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, induction

Basically this question consists of two questions that are intertwined:

1) I would like to find the (unique) solution $x_{\mathrm{solution}}$ to the N-th polynomial 
in $x$ for $x>\frac{-1}{max(a)}$, namely

$\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}a_i\cdot \left( \prod\limits_{j=1,j \neq i}^{N} (1+a_j \cdot x )  \right) \cdot (1-x)\right)  - C \cdot \prod\limits_{i=1}^{N} (1+a_i \cdot x)  =0$

for general $a_i >0$ and for any $C \in \Bbb{N}$. As you can see all summands are of order N.

It is known, that there is only **one real solution** for $x>\frac{-1}{max(a)}$ (even though the polynomial can be of high order), and from numerical studies I know $x_{\mathrm{solution}}$ also solves the related polynomial

$\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\left( \prod\limits_{j=1,j \neq i}^{N} (1+a_j \cdot x )  \right) \cdot (1-x)\right)  + C \cdot \prod\limits_{i=1}^{N} (1+a_i \cdot x)  =(N+C)\cdot \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{N} (1+a_i \cdot x)\right)\cdot (1-x)$

2) Is there any way to prove that both these polynomials are solved by the same real $x$? I know it is true numerically, I just dont know how to prove it.

For $N=1$, for example, the first equation is linear, the second quadratic, and one can easily check that $x_{\mathrm{solution}}=\frac{a_1-C}{a_1 \cdot (C+1)}$.

Maybe one can somehow work by induction to higher $N$?

Comment: Are you sure that the upper limit in
$\prod\limits_{j \neq i}^{n-1} (1+a_j  x ) $
is not $n$?
This is of degree $n-2$
except when $i=n$.

Comment: Yes thanks! I updated the description to make it crystal clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$f(x)
=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i\prod\limits_{j \neq i}^{n} (1+a_j  x ) 
$,
$g(x)
=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i  x) 
$,
and
$h(x)
=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\prod\limits_{j \neq i}^{n} (1+a_j  x ) 
$.

Your claim is that
$u(x)
=f(x)-cg(x)$
and
$v(x)
=h(x)+cg(x)-(n+c)(1-x)g(x)
$
have a common root
for some $c$.

I will show that if
$0 < c 
\lt \sum_{i=1}^n a_i
$,
there is a common root $x$ 
such that
$c
=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }
$.

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i\prod\limits_{j \neq i}^{n} (1+a_j  x )\\
&=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i\dfrac{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n} (1+a_j  x )}{1+a_i  x }\\
&=(1-x)g(x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }\\
&=(1-x)g(x)f_1(x)\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
h(x)
&=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\prod\limits_{j \neq i}^{n} (1+a_j  x )\\
&=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n} (1+a_j  x )}{1+a_ix}\\
&=(1-x)g(x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+a_ix}\\
&=(1-x)g(x)h_1(x)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
u(x)
&=f(x)-cg(x)\\
&=(1-x)g(x)f_1(x)-cg(x)\\
&=g(x)((1-x)f_1(x)-c)\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
v(x)
&=h(x)+cg(x)-(n+c)(1-x)g(x)\\
&=(1-x)g(x)h_1(x)+cg(x)-(n+c)(1-x)g(x)\\
&=g(x)((1-x)h_1(x)+c-(n+c)(1-x))\\
&=g(x)((1-x)(h_1(x)-(n+c))+c)\\
\end{array}
$

The positive root(s) of $u(x)$
satisfy
$(1-x)f_1(x)=c
$
or
$x = 1-\dfrac{c}{f_1(x)}
$.

The positive root(s) of $v(x)$
satisfy
$(1-x)(n+c-h_1(x))=c
$
or
$x = 1-\dfrac{c}{n+c-h_1(x)}
$.

These are equal if
$f_1(x)
=n+c-h_1(x)
$
or
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }
=n+c-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+a_i  x }
$
or
$n+c
=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1+a_i}{1+a_i  x }
$.

If all $a_i = a$,
this is
$n+c
=n\dfrac{1+a}{1+ax}
$
or
$(n+c)(1+ax)
=n(1+a)
$
or
$(n+c)ax
=n(1+a)-(n+c)
=na-c
$
or
$x
=\dfrac{na-c}{a(n+c)}
$.

In the general case,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1+a_i}{1+a_i  x }
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1+a_ix-a_ix+a_i}{1+a_i  x }\\
&=n+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i(1-x)}{1+a_i  x }\\
&=n+(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }\\
\end{array}
$

so

$n+c
=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1+a_i}{1+a_i  x }
$
when
$c
=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }
$.

If
$d(x)
=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }
$,
then
$d(0) 
=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i
$
and
$d(1) = 0$,
so if
$0 < c 
\lt \sum_{i=1}^n a_i
$,
there is an $x$ such that
$d(x) = c$.

For this $x$,
$f_1(x) = d(x)$
and

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{v(x)}{g(x)}
&=(1-x)(h_1(x)-(n+c))+c\\
&=(1-x)(h_1(x)-(n+d(x)))+d(x)\\
&=(1-x)(h_1(x)-(n+(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }))+(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }\\
&=(1-x)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+a_ix}-(n+(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }))+(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }\\
&=(1-x)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{1+a_ix}-\dfrac{(1-x)a_i}{1+a_i  x }+\dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i  x }\right)-n)\\
&=(1-x)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1+a_i-a_i+xa_i}{1+a_ix}\right)-n)\\
&=(1-x)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1+xa_i}{1+a_ix}\right)-n)\\
&=0\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Hmm the answer is probably correct, but only for the limited case of $c<\sum a_i$. I would like to know it for any c, and I think I have not been specific enough, so I modified the question again to make sure what is required: c has to be an integer (any), including 0. For any integer $c$, and for any positive $a_i$, there is a common root to both polynomials.

Comment: Just to remind you, the roots do not have to be positive, and sometimes are negative, just $x>\frac{-1}{max(a)}$

Comment: I think with your derivation one can actually write down a solution that is valid for all $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the upper limit in
$\prod\limits_{j \neq i}^{n-1} (1+a_j  x ) $
is not $n$?
This is of degree $n-2$
except when $i=n$.

I will make this
modification below.

Let
$f(x)
=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i\prod\limits_{j \neq i}^{n} (1+a_j  x ) 
$,
$g(x)
=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i  x) 
$,
and
$h(x)
=(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\prod\limits_{j \neq i}^{n} (1+a_j  x ) 
$.

Your claim is that
$u(x)
=f(x)-cg(x)$
and
$v(x)
=h(x)+cg(x)-(n+c)(1-x)g(x)
$
have a common root
for some $c$.

I will show that
this is true if
all the $a_i$ are equal
to $a$
and the root is
$x =  \dfrac{an-c}{a(n+c)}
$.

If all the $a_i = 1$,
$f(x) = h(x)$
so this becomes
$f(x)-cg(x)$
and
$f(x)+cg(x)-(n+c)(1-x)g(x)$
have a common root.
For this root,
$-cg(x) = cg(x)-(n+c)(1-x)g(x)
$
or
$0
=g(x)(2c-(1-x)(n+c))
$.

If $x > 0$
then
$g(x)\ne 0$,
so
$2c
=(1-x)(n+c)
$
or
$x(n+c)
=n-c
$
or
$x = \dfrac{n-c}{n+c}
$.

Also,
in this case,
$f(x) = h(x)
=n(1-x)(1+x)^{n-1}
$
and
$g(x)
=(1+x)^n
$,
so

$\begin{array}\\
u(x)
&=n(1-x)(1+x)^{n-1}-c(1+x)^n\\
&=(1+x)^{n-1}(n(1-x)-c(1+x))\\
\end{array}
$

with root
$n(1-x)=c(1+x)$
or
$x = \dfrac{n-c}{n+c}
$;

$\begin{array}\\
v(x)
&=h(x)+cg(x)-(n+c)(1-x)g(x)\\
&=n(1-x)(1+x)^{n-1}+(1+x)^n(c-(n+c)(1-x))\\
&=(1+x)^{n-1}(n(1-x)+(1+x)(c-(n+c)(1-x))\\
&=(1+x)^{n-1}(n(1-x)+c(1+x)-(n+c)(1-x^2))\\
&=(1+x)^{n-1}((n+c)x^2+x(c-n)+n+c-(n+c))\\
&=x(1+x)^{n-1}((n+c)x+(c-n))\\
\end{array}
$

Again, this has root
$x = \dfrac{n-c}{n+c}
$.

If all the $a_i = a$,
$f(x) = ah(x)$
and
$h(x)
=n(1-x)(1+ax)^{n-1}
$
and
$g(x)
=(1+ax)^n
$,
so

$\begin{array}\\
u(x)
&=an(1-x)(1+ax)^{n-1}-c(1+ax)^n\\
&=(1+ax)^{n-1}(an(1-x)-c(1+ax))\\
\end{array}
$

with root
$an(1-x)=c(1+ax)$
or
$an-c 
= ax(n+c)
$
or
$x = \dfrac{an-c}{a(n+c)}
$;

$\begin{array}\\
v(x)
&=h(x)+cg(x)-(n+c)(1-x)g(x)\\
&=n(1-x)(1+ax)^{n-1}+(1+ax)^n(c-(n+c)(1-x))\\
&=(1+ax)^{n-1}(n(1-x)+(1+ax)(c-(n+c)(1-x)))\\
&=(1+x)^{n-1}(n(1-x)+c(1+ax)-(n+c)(1+(a-1)x-ax^2))\\
&=(1+x)^{n-1}(a(n+c)x^2+x(ac-n-(a-1)(n+c))+n+c-(n+c))\\
&=(1+x)^{n-1}(a(n+c)x^2+x(c-an))\\
&=x(1+x)^{n-1}(a(n+c)x+(c-an))\\
\end{array}
$

Again, this has root
$x = \dfrac{an-c}{a(n+c)}
$.

Comment: No this is wrong I think, when i=n it is of the same degree as i=1, i=2 etc.. the product has degree N-1 and the extra factor (x-1) pushes it to N. Also checking with wolfram I am getting a different answer for N=2 already I think, but let me check.

Comment: Wow impressive :D thanks. However this is the solution if all $a$ are equal, a very special one, and it is not true that this is the only possible way to solve these equations. There is also a solution if the a's are not equal! For example each of the N $a_i$ can have a different value, and there still is one unique solution.

Comment: Just to comment, I just found out there can be actually more solutions, so I added the extra requirement $x>\frac{-1}{max(a)}$ for which really only one solution exists.

Comment: See my second answer.